# How to check a polyline is self intersecting

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-9.3

How to check weather a **single polyline** is self intersecting to itself.
using arcobject C#

Comment: The code given in C# is not giving any result it giving true though the poly line is self intersecting.

Comment: That is when two poly lines intersection. But here a poly line intersects by itself. I need that code in c#.

Comment: @Jagadesh: Did you see the second answer on that question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/41615/442?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I already tried that one but doesn't worked for me.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Desktop are you running? There are several bugs in ITopologicalOperator as I have mentioned in comments on that Answer

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe: 9.3.1

Comment: If you are using 9.3 you could try calling the Check Geometry tool using the GeoProcessor?

Comment: No idea about ArcGIS , but is OGC software like postGIS consider mentione polyline not valid , which can be found using ST_IsValid(geom). Mentioned method can be found from several program.